Components of Earth's angular velocity when vertical axis is aligned with apparent gravity
I've been reading the book "Classical Mechanics" by John Taylor, and in the chapter about noninertial reference frames, it states that the direction of $g$ (the apparent gravity, which includes the centrifugal force) is not necessarily aligned with the direction of $g_0$ (the true gravity direction, directed towards the centre of the Earth).
It goes on to establish a coordinate system for a point on the surface of the Earth at colatitude $\theta$, where the vertical axis is aligned with $g$, and the horizontal axes are aligned with north and east. It then states that if $\Omega$ (the angular velocity of the Earth) is vertical in the standard coordinate system, we can calculate the components of $\Omega$ in the coordinate system described above as:
$(0, \ \Omega \sin(\theta), \ \Omega \cos(\theta))$
See attached diagram.
I'm confused by this because, as far as I understand, this calculation would only make sense if the coordinate system's vertical direction was aligned with $g_0$ (so that a vector from the point on the Earth's surface along this direction would be directed towards the centre of the Earth), rather than along $g$ (which would mean a vector from the point on the Earth's surface along this direction would not be directed towards the centre of the Earth, due to the included centrifugal force).
Is this just an unstated approximation being made (because the directions of $g$ and $g_0$ are similar), or have I just misunderstood what the book means?
Any help would be really appreciated.


I have edited the question, to use the stackexchange support for math notation

I'm confused about the definition of "colatitude"  \lambda.  If it means 90-\theta, then the formula for omega components is not correct.  If it refers to an alternate nearby latitude where g and g0 are in the same direction, then maybe that answers your question?

What is the date on the book? In geodesy, $\lambda$ is latitude, and $\phi$ is geodetic latitude (which not exactly aligned with $\vec g$ b/c of the vertical deflection). The statement "aligned with g" is ambiguous. Usually NED (north-east-down) is used, a NEU is left-handed.

Considering the body being at a height already, geff (g, here) should not bother the free fall of body. 'g' is for bodies that are in contact with Earth, or in Earth, thus rotating along Earth's axis w.r.t. an observer from outer space.
Theoretically, a body not in contact with Earth should only experience a radial acceleration towards centre of Earth.
If any discrepancies, please let me know.

Notification: The orbit of a satellite in low Earth orbit is subject to an effect that arises from the fact that the Earth's gravitational attraction is not quite spherically symmetric. For a satellite orbiting a perfect sphere: the plane of the orbit will have a constant orientation. Satellites orbiting the Earth: there is a precession of that plane. There is a type of orbit that capitalizes on that effect: Sun-synchronous orbit That orbit is designed to have just the right precession such that the orbital plane precesses in a year cycle.

About $g$ and $g_0$. The angle between $\vec{g}$ and $\vec{g}_0$ is very small, it is at its largest at 45 degrees latitude, and even there it is only around 0.1 of a degree.
About the Earth. It is customary to treat the Earth as spherical. The deviation from a perfect sphere is very small; the equatorial radius is about 21 kilometers more than the polar radius (on an averaged radius of 6,378) The first approximation that takes that difference in radius into account is called 'the reference ellipsoid'.

Now comes the twist:
If you take a point on the reference ellipsoid, you can take the vector $\vec{g}$, and extend it all the way towards the geometric center of the Earth, and you see that that vector does not quite hit the geometric center.
Take the vector $\vec{g}_0$ and extend it all the way towards the geometric center of the Earth: it does not quite hit the geometric center of the Earth either.

About the true gravity:
It is only in the case of a perfect sphere, with spherically symmetrical density distribution that the center of gravitational attraction coincides with the geometric center.
To visualize the center of gravitational attraction of the reference ellipsoid, think of an extreme version: the center of gravitational attraction of a disk. Let's say you are on the rim of the disk. Gravity falls off with the inverse square of the distance, so the parts of the disk close to you attract you stronger than the parts further away. So: from most angles the center of gravitational attraction of a disk does not coincide with the geometric center.
In the case of the reference ellipsoid, with its minimal equatorial bulge: the deviation is very small, but the difference between $\vec{g}$ and $\vec{g}_0$ is also that small.

So: for simplicity the Earth is treated as spherical, and the $\vec{g_0}$ of the spherical Earth is used, because that one does originate from the spherical Earth's geometric center.

Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm confused when you say that "the g of the spherical Earth is used, because that one does originate from the spherical Earth's geometric centre". I thought that it's "g0" that originates from the spherical Earth's geometric centre, whereas "g" is offset from that, due to the centrifugal force, which is what I was trying to get at with my original question?

Also, the book specifies an assumption that the Earth is considered as a perfect sphere, so I'm not sure if the idea of a reference ellipsoid helps solve the confusion I'm having?

@NickKovac I edited my answer, replacing $\vec{g}$ with $\vec{g}_0$ For John Taylor the tricky situation is: he wants to bring out the rotation effect, but he also wants to treat the Earth as spherical. On the actual Earth (with its equatorial bulge): at every point the local surface is perpendicular to $\vec{g}$ at that point.  In my opinion: a textbook author who uses a perfectly spherical Earth is treating the Earth as a non-rotating celestial body. Both on a non-rotating celestial body and on a rotating celestial body: use $\vec{g}$. (Non-rotating: $\vec{g}$ and $\vec{g}_0$ coincide.)

I'm sorry, I'm still confused :( You're saying that if we used a reference ellipsoid, that neither g nor g0 would meet the geometric centre. But the book isn't using that ellipsoid, so I don't see why that's important... you then say that if we use a perfect sphere, that g0 would meet the geometric centre. That makes sense, and the book is using a perfect sphere. But then the book uses g as the vertical axis, not g0, and I don't see how that can be used to calculate the components of omega in the diagram, since it doesn't meet the geometric centre, so the trigonometry doesn't make sense.

I feel like there's probably something fundamental about this I'm not understanding, since I'm having trouble with your explanation too. I do appreciate your answer so thank you for that.

Another way of phrasing the problem I'm having might be that if we're using g for the vertical axis, then on the diagram, the vector representing the z axis would no longer be parallel to the line from the centre of the sphere to the point O on the boundary. That would only be true if we're using g0.

@NickKovac For John Taylor the tricky situation is: he wants to bring out the rotation effect, but he also wants to treat the Earth as spherical. Anyway, clearly you need to bring your question to a threaded forum, such as physics forums. Stackexchange policy is that comment space is not for protracted discourse, and I endorse that policy. (I mean by 'threaded': that the forum is conversational; you can keep adding follow-up questions.)

No problem, I'll do that. Thanks.
